# String path to array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert HTML-style form array to PHP array.
I tried a lot of solutions but I only get errors or reference ("pointer") problems.

The HTML array pathes are formatted like this :

- `tree[]`
- `tree2[key1]`
- `tree2[key2][key3]`
- `tree3[][key4]`

Here is my method that builds the array, where I removed the code that does not works (because it were only garbage) :

```
private function addFieldToBag(BagCollectionInterface $bag, $name, $content)
{
    # The field is not an array component
    if(!$firstKey = strpos($name, '['))
    {
        $bag->add($name, $content);
    }
    # The field is part of an array (eg. "tree[key][]")
    else
    {
        preg_match_all('/(?:\\[(\\w*)\\])/', $name, $treeComponents);
        # $treeComponents[1] = ['key', ''], will be used to build the array

        $treeRootName = substr($name, 0, $firstKey);
        # $treeRootName = 'tree'

        # eg. "tree" array doesn't exists yet 
        if(!array_key_exists($treeRootName, $bag->all()))
        {
            $treeRoot = [];
        }
        else
        {
            $treeRoot = $bag->get($treeRootName);
        }

        # Here I want to build the array using :
        # $treeRoot as the array root, containing data or not.
        # $treeComponents[1] as the path to build
        # $content as the final scalar value of the path
        # eg. on tree[][key] with value of 'scalarValue':
        # $treeRoot = [
        #   0 => [
        #       key => scalarValue
        #   ]
        # ]

        # Reassignation of the array to the bag,
        # because I can not modify the array returned by $bag->get(name); :(
        $bag->add($treeRootName, $treeRoot);
    }
}
```

I'm lost, thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show your input data?

Comment: The `$name` argument is the raw HTML-like array node name, `tree[key][]` in the method example, or like the possible values in the list at the top of the post. The `$content` argument is a string.

Comment: Without understanding your whole code and problem at moment,`!$firstKey = strpos($name, '[')` cannot work. You need to put the assignment between parentheses: `!($firstKey = strpos($name, '['))`

Comment: Not necessary :) This works!

Comment: Ok, then I post it as an answer ... I wasn't sure if that was all..

Comment: Sorry, I said "not necessary" for the parentheses. Actually, $firstKey is assigned correctly and then $treeRootName too. Maybe the parentheses were necessary in previous versions of PHP, but currently with 5.6.6 it works.
The code cannot work here because it is incomplete. Look at the lines beginning with "Here I want to build the array using", that's where the array should be built according to the $treeRootName.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the php version. Its because of operator precedence which has not changed in any PHP version. `!$firstKey` gets executed *before* the assignment

Comment: This is not true, at least in that 'if' case... The assignment is being done before.
If `!$firstkey` would be executed first, I would get an `Undefined variable` notice, then the `else` would never be reached, and that's not the case. This code **works** and the parentheses are useless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71425/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-morgan-touverey-quilling).